# Document Version Control System

Tags: document-management, version-control

I'm new to all this versioning business so please help me understand the different versioning software out there that will suit my need. I've come to a sad realisation that I need to start versioning my documents and code because when I was transferring data through USB, it got really messy and I lost a lot of work in the process. Lost all my design work because I copied the wrong folder and thinking it was safe to delete, did a "shift-del"... Stupidity a side - lesson learnt.

So I did a lot of searching around, and I've settled on Git (on BitBucket) for versioning the source code. However, I'm having a hard time finding a solution for:

- Documents such as word docx, pdf
- Design models such as UML and flowcharts
- Project management and schedules such as Excel spreadsheet or MS Project deliverables

My requirements are as follow:

- Individual file checkin/checkout capability (for collaboration)
- File locking on checkout (to prevent conflicts)
- Ability to a commit a new version without checking in (allow to keep offline if I'm the only one working on the document. On a one man project I would simply keep everything checked out and simply commit for versioning.)
- Automatic version numbering on commit or checkin

I currently have personal cloud sync to keep file history on each save. However, this is presented in a meaningless state and serves only as security should I make a mistake. The requirements stated above will add a meaningful way for me to review and roll back on "milestones".

Please advise if there is anything out there that meet this requirement.

Comment: Just a comment, you seem to be confusing Git with other VCSs. Git is decentralized, for example, so there isn't really a checkout/checkin process.

Comment: Which is exactly why I'm asking this question. I'm using git for my code. But I want a versioning system for my documents as well.

Answer (score 3):

Version Control Systems generally do not care about what the files fed to them represent – though they tread file types differently (e.g. binary files). So we can leave the file-specific stuff aside.

From your description, it looks to me as if **[Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)** might be a good match:

- **Individual file checkin/checkout capability (for collaboration):** Possible. Simply specify the file(s) you want to check-in, e.g. `svn ci file.doc`, `svn ci *.pdf`, or `svn ci files/*`
- **File locking on checkout (to prevent conflicts):** Possible. Use `svn lock <target>`, with `<target>` being interpreted as in my previous example – so you can lock a single file, multiple files, or entire directories
- **Ability to a commit a new version without checking in:** No. That would only work with a de-centralized system like *Git*, which keeps copies of the repository on each machine – but then you'd normally have no locking.
- **Automatic version numbering on commit or checkin:** That's a substantial feature of every VCS I'd say, so it's naturally available with SVN as well.

You will have a hard time finding a system matching all your requirements, so you will probably have to decide *on what* to compromise. With *Git* there won't be file locking (due to its de-centralized structure, this cannot be done) – which to me looks more important than the "local commits". The latter you could "substitute" by (temporarily) keeping copies of the file in a separate directory, which of course can be excluded from the repository using e.g. `.svnignore`.

Comment: It is possible with Subversion to commit a file without releasing the lock (`svn commit --no-unlock`). I believe this feature could provide a "Yes" answer to point 3.

Comment: @GregHewgill not "literally" (as commit/checkin are the same with SVN IMHO), but from what the OP wants this seems at least a "partial yes" – so +1 to that from me!

Comment: SVN, like a lot of VCSs does not do a very good job on binary files such as word documents, you are better off using markdown or similar for the files and generating Word if needed using pandoc.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: I don't believe that is the case. SVN diffs files byte-by-byte to store them (as opposed to when doing an svn diff). I have a lot of issues with SVN, but that is one of its strong points. ref: https://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/209/16/how-does-subversion-handle-binary-files

Comment: SVN is _better_ than say CSV in this respect but if you have large binary files with large deltas, (often the case for even a small change in zipped formats like docx), you can still get server slowdown. Personally I admire hg for its zipdoc and bigfiles extensions to handle this sort of issue.  I still advise mardown for document storage as you are not subject to the MS _"I will not read that its from 3 versions ago"_ syndrome.

Comment: @SteveBarnes While I'm agreeing that [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is a better fit, I'd suggest having that discussion elsewhere – as, concerning the OPs request, that's "taking the horse by its tail". True and valid as it is, we are [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Git and most other source code-oriented tools are not optimal for document management.
What you need is a document management system or [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) system.

[NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com/) is exactly that:

- Store a hierarchy of folders and documents of any type/size.
- Modifications are saved as new versions.
- You can always revert to a previous version.
- Check out a document, edit it, then check it back in. It will be locked so that other users can not modify it at the same time.
- Check out/in is not an obligation, you can edit documents without it.

It is free, and open source.

There is a web interface that shows your documents, and allows you to preview them, download them, or move/delete/copy/etc.

You can also associate metadata to a document, for instance a draft/final/obsolete state, or workflow information: waiting for approval / approved for sending / sent to customer.

You mentioned file sync. Using NemakiWare exclusively via the web interface is possible, but NemakiWare also supports the [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) protocol, so I suggest using [CmisSync](http://cmissync.com/) which will synchronize your documents to/from your computer's filesystem, handling conflicts like Dropbox.

[image: NemakiWare UI]

*Disclaimer: My company makes both NemakiWare and CmisSync*